# String to date in Oracle with milliseconds

Tags: oracle, to-date

I want to convert the follow string to date:

```
2004-09-30 23:53:48,140000000
```

I tried:

```
to_date('#', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9')
```

But [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) keep throwing this error:

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized.
```

FF9 is incorrect for Oracle, any suggestion?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`Oracle` stores only the fractions up to second in a `DATE` field.

Use `TIMESTAMP` instead:

```
SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP('2004-09-30 23:53:48,140000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9')
FROM    dual
```

, possibly casting it to a `DATE` then:

```
SELECT  CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2004-09-30 23:53:48,140000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9') AS DATE)
FROM    dual
```

Comment: Datetime Format Elements: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can use fractional seconds with to_date or the DATE type in Oracle.  I think you need to_timestamp which returns a TIMESTAMP type.