# Using Oracle to_date function for date string with milliseconds

Tags: oracle, to-date

I have to perform some inserts into an Oracle DB. I have some dates
in the following format

```
'23.12.2011 13:01:001'
```

Following the documentation I wrote inserts **to_date** as follows:

```
to_date('23.12.2011 13:01:01', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

which works properly. Now I have dates with milliseconds with the format

```
'23.12.2011 13:01:001'
```

I've tried the following:

```
to_date('23.12.2011 13:01:001', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSFF3')
```

which is incorrect (delivers an error 01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized").

Which "String" should I use for this format with milliseconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to date in Oracle with milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758219/string-to-date-in-oracle-with-milliseconds)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

An Oracle `DATE` does not store times with more precision than a second.  You cannot store millisecond precision data in a `DATE` column.

Your two options are to either truncate the string of the milliseconds before converting it into a `DATE`, i.e.

```
to_date( substr('23.12.2011 13:01:001', 1, 19), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )
```

or to convert the string into a `TIMESTAMP` that does support millisecond precision

```
to_timestamp( '23.12.2011 13:01:001', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSFF3' )
```

Answer (score 18):

TO_DATE supports conversion to DATE datatype, which doesn't support milliseconds.  If you want millisecond support in Oracle, you should look at TIMESTAMP datatype and TO_TIMESTAMP function.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 12):

For three digits millisecond:

```
TO_CHAR(LN_AUTOD_UWRG_DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
```

For six digits millisecond:

```
TO_CHAR(LN_AUTOD_UWRG_DTTM,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
```

Comment: *cough* 'six digits millisecond' should probably be '6 digits microsecond'

Answer (score 11):

You can try this format `SS.FF` for milliseconds:

to_timestamp(table_1.date_col,'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF')

For more details:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm

Answer (score -10):

You have to change date class to timestamp.

```
String s=df.format(c.getTime());
java.util.Date parsedUtilDate = df.parse(s);  
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedUtilDate.getTime());
```

Comment: What does Java have to do with Oracle PL/SQL?