# Change date format to Oracle Date Format

Tags: java, oracle10g

I am reading few data from a text file using java code,along with date in format (30-OCT-2012 12-22-44-991) and i want to store these details in Oracle Database but in the same format as used by oracle.
I tried To_date but of no use, it gives error.
Kindly help me.

Comment: Please show the code you tried, and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in Java to parse your String to a `java.util.Date`. Then use a `PreparedStatement` and [set the date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) on that.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
You can use a `PreparedStatement` like Aleksander Blomskøld already suggested and with help from [Using Oracle to_date function for date string with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180014/using-oracle-to-date-function-for-date-string-with-milliseconds):

```
final sql = "INSERT into IFT_VEHICLE_STATUS (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, UPDATED_AT) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, to_timestamp(?, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS:SSFF3'))";
final PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setInt(1, 81000000);
pstmt.setInt(2, 162000000);
pstmt.setDate(3, oracleDate);

pstmt.execute();
```

**Old:**
Are you trying to convert a `java.util.Date` into a `java.sql.Timestamp`? You could do that like this:

```
try {
    final Date javaUtilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2012-01-20 11:46:06");
    System.out.println("javaUtilDate = " + javaUtilDate);
    final Timestamp oracleDate = new Timestamp(javaUtilDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("oracleDate = " + oracleDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will give the following output:

```
javaUtilDate = Fri Jan 20 11:46:06 CET 2012
oracleDate = 2012-01-20 11:46:06.0
```

Comment: I converted the date to Timestamp and the oracle column also is Timestamp. but still my query is not working.

Comment: query i am using
INSERT into IFT_VEHICLE_STATUS (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, UPDATED_AT) VALUES ('lat','lon','timestampdate');

Comment: Can you use a `PreparedStatement` like Aleksander Blomskøld suggested and with help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180014/using-oracle-to-date-function-for-date-string-with-milliseconds:

   PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into IFT_VEHICLE_STATUS (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, UPDATED_AT) VALUES (?, ?, to_timestamp(?, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS:SSFF3'))");
   pstmt.setInt(1, 81000000);
   pstmt.setInt(2, 162000000);
   pstmt.setDate(3, oracleDate);