# Why SELECT DISTINCT returns twice the same value?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, distinct

I have a table in Oracle, which has `DATE` column. I can observe that `SELECT DISTINCT` returns duplicates:

```
select distinct myDate from myTable;

myDate
----------------------------
2009-09-05 00:00:00          
2009-09-05 00:00:00
```

But:

```
select distinct to_char(myDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from myTable;

TO_CHAR(myDate,'DD-MM-YYYYHH24:MI:SS')
------------------------------------------------
05-09-2009 00:00:00
```

And next queries, which can tell more:

```
select count(*) from myTable;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        12 

select myDate, count(*) from myTable group by myDate;

myDate                        COUNT(*)
---------------------------- ----------
2009-09-05 00:00:00                   6 
2009-09-05 00:00:00                   6 


select count(*) from myTable where myDate='2009-09-05';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         6
```

What can be the reason of such behaviour? As far as I know there is no more information stored in `DATE` column which can make the difference (no time zone, no miliseconds).

---

**EDIT: table DDL**

Unfortunately I can't post whole DDL. Definition of the column is:

```
myDate DATE NOT NULL
```

What can be important, table is partitioned using this column:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (myDate)
(
PARTITION P_19991231 VALUES LESS THAN 
    (TO_DATE('1999-12-31 00:00:00',
           'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
);
```

There is more partitions in the table.

And also `ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT` is ON.

Comment: can you give us a schema of the table?

Comment: Why don't you change the NLS format for SQL*Plus so it displays the date ***and*** the time?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I changed it and edited my question. But it shows nothing (at least for me).

Comment: That sure looks strange....

Comment: Maybe a long-shot, but might you have BCE dates, incorrectly entered (presumably) as -2009? You can see those by using `SYYYY` instead of `YYYY`. If you use `YYYY`, explicitly or in your NLS settings, the two would look the same when displayed.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks, I've checked it, but it's not the case...

Comment: That's a shame, I had a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b9cd/4) to demonstrate *8-) Can you `dump()` the date values to see what they show - only other thing I can think of is some kind of internal corruption.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you, I didn't know `dump()` function. I used it and it showed the same for all records: `Typ=12 Len=7: 120,109,9,5,1,1,1`. So it has to be some internal error and I can reproduce it. I think that it can be connected with partitioning (this column is partitioning key).

Comment: Is it showing that for 12 records or for 6? How many records do you think there really are? Do you have a partition around that date? Not that it really matters, if that is the only value it's showing then you probably need to raise a service request with Oracle to see if this is a bug in your particular version.

Comment: @AlexPoole The problem was in partitions. I made an exchange and did mistake in it. I will add answer with details in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in partitioning. I made few `EXCHANGE PARTITIONS` operations without validation and as a result few records was placed on incorrect partition (not in its range). In such situation comparisons and `SELECT DISTINCT` didn't work correct.

Answer (score 0):

A precision problem: after the seconds, you have milliseconds. You have in your table 2 rows with dates in the same second, but not with the same milliseconds. When you execute a `SELECT DISTINCT` against the dates, they are distinct, so you have 2 rows. But using the `to_char` function, you round the dates to the seconds and you have only one row returned.

To group by dates, you must be sure that the date is **exactly** the same.

Comment: Are you sure that `DATE` type has miliseconds? As far as I know it end on the seconds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180014/using-oracle-to-date-function-for-date-string-with-milliseconds

Comment: Try to execute this: `select distinct to_char(myDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from myTable;`. FF indicates the fractions of seconds.

Comment: @eternay: the `FFx` is only valid for `TIMESTAMP` columns. A `DATE` does not have milliseconds, only seconds.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are right. I was thinking with timestamp columns.