# How to convert date to datetime in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, date-formatting

i have a date in oracle with this format `DD-MM-YYY` and i want to convert it to datetime with this other format `DD-MM-YYY HH24:MI` how can i proceed?

I've tried this but nothing is working :

```
to_date(the_date,'DD-MM-YYY HH24:MI')
```

and also this:

```
to_date(to_char(date_debut_p),'DD-MM-YYY HH24:MI')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180014/using-oracle-to-date-function-for-date-string-with-milliseconds

Comment: `to_ CHAR`(the_date,'DD-MM-YYY HH24:MI')` assuming `the_date` is a date.

Answer (score 25):

> i have a date in oracle with this format DD-MM-YYY and i want to convert it to datetime with this other format DD-MM-YYY HH24:MI

No, you are confused. **[Oracle does not store dates in the format you see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28298920/3989608)**. **It is internally stored in `7 bytes` with each byte storing different components of the datetime value.**

**DATE** data type always has both **date** and **time** elements up to a precision of **seconds**.

If you want to display, use **TO_CHAR** with proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

For example,

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM
-------------------
11/25/2015 22:25:42
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle `DATE` datatype ALWAYS contains (stores) time.

If you want to see it, you can use function TO_CHAR.

If you want to add, for example, 1 hour, you can just use `date_debut_p+1/24`.

Comment: to_char('09/01/15') returns me 09/01/15

Comment: @JoelPatrickNdzie '09/01/15' is alerady char! You should take your date field and make `to_char(date_fiekd, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to covert to timestamp, you can do the following:

Select to_timestamp(date_column, 'DD-MM-YYY') from table;

However, if you want in the required format, you can do the following:

Select  to_char(to_timestamp(date_column, 'DD-MON-YY'), 'DD-MM-YYY HH24:MI')
from table;

Hope it helps..