# How to get the full timestamp values from Oracle DB to Excel

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I have a column value

> 21-Sep-23 06.34.45.676676888 AM

I need fetch exactly same as this values. I have tried below query

```
to_char(Date,'DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS AM') as Date
```

Which will give below result

> 21-Sep-23 06.34.45 AM

Expected Output :

> 21-Sep-23 06.34.45.676676888 AM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180014/using-oracle-to-date-function-for-date-string-with-milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MI` for minutes (`MM` is month as a number) and `FF9` for the fractional seconds with 9 digits of precision:

```sql
TO_CHAR(timestamp_column, 'DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:SS.FF9 AM') AS timestamp_column
```

*Note: `HH` and `HH12` are interchangeable but `HH12` makes it explicit that you are formatting the value as a 12-hour clock.*

*Note 2: `DATE` is a reserved word and cannot be used as for an unquoted identifier; you either need to use a quoted identifier or name the column something other than `DATE`.*