# oracle - to_Date format

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

What format would you use to convert this CHAR value into a date?

```
Apr  9 1996  2:11:00:000PM


ie. select to_date('Apr  9 1996  2:11:00:000PM','???') from dual;
```

Has anyone found a good reference because all the ones I see expect that the hour has a preceding 0 to start with.

Comment: Please refer to this 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/1758219/1268469

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the sample with your date string.

```
select to_date(
to_char(to_timestamp('Apr 9 1996 2:11:00:000PM','MON DD YYYY hh:mi:ss:FF3PM'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'),
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')
from dual;
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

First:
TO_DATE doesn't support fractional seconds, so you have to play around with TO_TIMESTAMP

Second: you have to use oracle's formats you can find a table of valid values [here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html)

At first glance a format like `'MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS:FF3 AM'` should work

Edit: too low on coffeine today, forgot the AM ^^ Sorry

Answer (score 1):

This might work (untested):

```
'Mon  dd YYYY   HH:MI:SS   AM'
```